# Georeferencing files that are orthogonal to a point on a sphere

Tags: gdal, georeferencing

I have about 65000 photos, each of them a square where an inscribed circle is radius 1 degree.

Each of these photos has an associated latitude and longitude of the center.

I'm trying to figure out how to georeference these photos with gdal so that I can warp them into a large, more sane latlong coordinate system.  Once I figure out one of them, it will be trivial to automate the rest, but I just can't figure out how to properly georeference an orthogonal photo.

For instance, tile 1 has a central latitude and longitude of 0.  Further, along the central X-axis it occupies 1 deg and along the y-axis, it occupies 1 degree.  Using the attached photo as a guide:

[image: Reference points]

NOTE: (long, lat)
A: 0,0
B: 0,.5
C: .5,.5
D: 0,-.5
E:-.5,-.5

The next photo in this series along longitude would have the following coordinates:

A:1,0
B: 1,.5
C: 1.5,.5
D: 1,-.5
E:.5,-.5

--

Likewise, a photo at the pole would have a central latitude of 90 and longitude of 0.  So

A: 0,90
B: 0,89.5
C: 90,89.5
D: 180,89.5
E: -90,89.5

Further, the next photo in this series would be rotated by 1 degree.  So

A: 1,90
B: 1,89.5
C: 91,89.5
D: -179,89.5
E: -89,89.5

An so and, so forth.

--

My proposed solution is something like:

```
gdal_translate -a_srs "+proj=ortho +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +a=6378140 +b=6378140 +units=d" input_000_00.jpg output_000_00.tif
```

But, when I do that and attempt to warp it, I get the following:

> ERROR 1: Unable to compute a transformation between pixel/line and georeferenced coordinates for test17990.tif.  There is no affine transformation and no GCPs.

Comment: All you need is to write world file, this might help http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162064/how-to-display-images-next-to-features-in-a-map

Answer (score 1):

You have specified degrees as units, but not added any information what coordinates your corner points have. Apart from that, `+units=d` is not listed with `proj -lu` and might be ignored.

You may try gdal_translate with `-a_ullr`, or add GCP points with `-gcp`.