# Python Script to apply the Northing and Easting of a photo center .shp file to a tiff.

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, geotiff-tiff

I have a group of tiffs I want to georeference. I have the photo centers for each of the tiffs but they are not linked. After looking at the comments I believe there would be a way to take the attribute of the .shp, Northing and Easting, and apply it to the tiff? The frame number for the photo is in the attribute table of the points. I assume you could use this to look into the folder and pull out the correct photo and reference it to said location. I hope this explains what I am looking for in a better light.

Comment: No, photo centres are only one of the three required parameters for transformation.. you need rotation and scale also.

Comment: Do you want to georeference images or instead create point locations where photos were taken that have hyperlinks/attachments which are those photos?

Comment: I want the photos to go to the location of the photo center when i bring them in. From there I will georeference them. It just takes me a long time to find the starting location because they have no spatial reference. And i have about 30000 photo centers

Comment: It sounds like what you have is unrectified (raw) aerial photography, to convert this into orthophotograpy you need to orthorectify it using the the parameters that should exist with each raw image and a DEM using specialized software, is this correct?

Comment: Have you looked into the new beta program at Esri called "Drone2Map"? If your photos have the correct information ( lat, long, altitude) then that software will do everything for you (stitch them together, create a 3D point cloud, etc.). It's pretty new, so you should check it out, especially considering you have 30k of photos! http://www.esri.com/products/drone2map

Comment: This will take you there http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162064/how-to-display-images-next-to-features-in-a-map

Comment: Thanks Felix this is what I was looking for! Can I just change the parameters to work with tiffs?