# Arcmap - add an image to a legend that is not part of layer symbology

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, legend, image

I am making a simple map, showing store locations on a background. Each store brand is displayed with an image (a coloured square with a letter e.g. Aldi might be a blue square with the letter "A" inside).

In the legend we want to display: Brand logo image - Symbology image - Name. 
Something like this:

[image]

How do I add the brand logo image to the legend?

I don't want to convert the legend to graphics, because I'm exporting a number of maps displaying different layers. I'm thinking of doing the following:

- Create a combined image of brand logo and symbol (there's only half a dozen of these so it's manageable)
- Duplicate the layer, but "move" the coordinates to display outside the visible map extent
- Use the combined images for the new layer symbology
- add the layer to the legend
- Remove the actual layer from the legend
- (The reason for the last two steps are so that I can still have the legend only showing switched on layers)

I think that would work but it seems inelegant.

Is there a better way of doing this?

E.g. is it possible to add an HTML tag to the legend item to add the logo?

Comment: Use dataframe instead of legend        and copy of your points placed on vertical line http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162064/displaying-images-next-to-features-in-arcmap/162218#162218d

Comment: I think a picture of what you are trying to achieve would help.