# Including image in callout using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, labeling, image

I'm using ArcMap 10.3 and creating a map of 30 properties where each property needs to include an image within the callout.

The final product has to be a printed map.  I'm familiar with creating basic Label Expressions using VBScrip, but need to know if there's a way to include an image?

My images are saved locally in a .tiff format and have a unique identifier as the file name. The other option I see is to add the image and resize into the callout, but this approach would take a lot of time and effort.

Here's an example

[image]

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/162064/115