# ArcMap 10.4.1, How to show linked pictures in layout data frame for a map book (using Basic License)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, data-driven-pages

I'm trying to create a map book for a tree inventory in ArcMap 10.4.1. I have a shapefile (no problem changing to a gdb) with 350 points, and the goal is to get a layout consisting of 3 data frames: two for maps showing each tree location with different layers underneath and the third one to show the picture of the tree itself. The first 2 are no problem, the issue is with the 3rd one.

The shp also has several fields that will show info in the layout via "Data driven page attribute", and what i'm having problems to achieve is a workaround to do this exact same thing but for images. Something in the attribute table that links the feature to its correspondent image, and for every page of the map book you'll end up with 2 data frames shoing the point location, and another one showing the picture linked to the point.

I know you can use attachments to do this, adding pictures and then setting data driven pages so each picture shows in the layout with the related point, but tied to work with a Basic License and this features are restricted to Standard and Advanced only.

Also i have tried working a gdb instead of a shp, creating a new field that lets attach raster images, but i have not found the way to show them in the data frame.

Is there any way to achieve this without having to use the attachment tools?

Comment: Maybe try this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162064/displaying-images-next-to-features-in-arcmap/162218#162218 using same xy for all pictures. Save pictures to catalog that supports definition  query.

Answer (score 0):

This is my workflow for this type of thing:

Add photos using the Geotagged Photos to Points tool.This is a Basic license level tool.  ArcMap will add a field for the filepath (i.e. C:\Photos\photo_1.jpg).

Add PhotoNumber field and number your photos how you want (i.e. sorted on descending latitude, time taken, etc).

Create grid index using photos layer as input.

Edit grid index layer so that each photo is located within a corresponding "grid" feature, and change PageNumber in the grid index layer to the corresponding photo number you already created. If you only have one photo per grid feature, you can do this with a spatial join.

Enable data driven pages with your grid index layer.

Insert Picture, then in Picture Properties, select the radio button for "Simple path from data driven pages" and select the path.

[image]

The photo will change each time you switch to a different page.