# ArcGIS - Show Point Marker Symbol based on attribute

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, layouts

I am using ArcGIS 10.4 and I have a point layer of universities. I want to show their logos in map layout. For each record in attribute table I have the link to respective logo of that university. I am using an option to assign a point marker symbol but the issue is **it is only allowing me to pick one by one by browsing the file explorer and choosing an image for each point**. I am not getting a way so that it picks from attribute table and then show the image.

Comment: Maybe this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162064/displaying-images-next-to-features-in-arcmap/162218#162218 can help

Comment: Thanks but no this does not worked

Comment: So, you want to put the symbols based on the url-path?

Comment: Yes
and they are 900 points approximately and each has its own logo

Comment: It may be worth looking at ArcGIS Pro's [attribute driven symbology](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/layer-properties/attribute-driven-symbology.htm) to see if that supports this use case.