# Adding Image Attachments to ArcGIS Pro Report

Tags: arcgis-pro, attachments, reports

I am trying to create a report that includes image attachments for each point in my feature class using ArcGIS Pro 2.4. I found some documentation explaining how to do it in Desktop using the Report Designer.

Is there similar functionality in Pro or a way to program it in Python?

Comment: See if this helps https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162064/displaying-images-next-to-features-in-arcmap/162218#162218

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but I'm not sure if it will work. My pictures are not showing up in the attribute table, but they do show up as attachments in the identification pop-up. I think this may be a difference in Pro vs Desktop.

Essentially what I'm trying to make is a PDF with each picture and its name that is one of the attributes listed in the table for that point.