# Adding ortophoto to map through hyperlink in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, hyperlink, orthophoto, addlayer

I would like to add layers (more specifically Orthophotos) through the hyperlink function in ArcMap 10.3.

With hyperlinks it is possible to add script (VBscript), documents and URL.
If I add the search path to my orthophotos inside a shapefile's attributes can I with the hyperlink open the photo in a photo viewer?
But I would like to be able to add that image to the mxd instead.

Do you have any ideas, a finished script or tips?

Comment: You wanna attach Images/orthophoto to a shapefile? or im understanding it wrong

Comment: You have a field with links to ortophotos and want to add them to the map? Use `da.SearchCursor` to read the field values and pass them to [Make Raster Layer](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-raster-layer.htm). I have not tried it though. Look at the examples in the link. Something like `for link in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(r'C:\path\to\shapefile.shp','fieldname_with_hyperlinks'):` then `arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(link[0], os.path.basename(link[0]))`

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162064/displaying-images-next-to-features-in-arcmap/162218#162218