# How to make a photo as a label on a point feature using ArcGIS/Arcmap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, attribute-table, photos

How to make a photo as a label on a point feature using ArcGIS/Arcmap.
In this case each point feature will display a different photo.

Someone has discussed this before, it can be seen at the following link:
[Displaying images next to features in ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162064/displaying-images-next-to-features-in-arcmap/)

But still confused when running it, such as where the python script is copied and pasted on Arcmap.

Comment: Do you need the images on a fixed map, or something someone can see when they click on the point? The latter involvesan HTML Popup.

Comment: Yes, I need a fixed map but not something like HTML Popup, because if I go into layout mode the html popup won't work.

Answer (score -1):

After making the suggested changes/edits, copy the script into the Geoprocessing Python box and hit enter twice to execute it. If it works as promised, you will have a point feature with map locations for the photos. So just add this to maps.

There is also a [geotagging photos](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/tools/data-management-toolbox/geotagged-photos-to-points.htm) tool I have used with GPS camera points, but those are already spatially aware so no set up or scripts are needed.