Create unique symbology of images per point based off of an attribute field
I have a point layer in ArcGIS Pro 3.2. The underlying attribute table has a field called ImagePath. In that field are unique UNC paths to images (e.g. *.png, etc.). I need to use that image as the symbol for that point feature on the map.
Currently, I have the following code, partly generated from genAI, but can't figure out how to get this working - if it's at all possible.
Does anyone have experience or advise with automating this process as a script in ArcGIS Pro?
import arcpy 
# Define the project and map 
    project = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")

map = project.listMaps("YourMapName")[0]

# Define the layer
layer = map.listLayers("YourLayerName")[0]

# Create a new unique value renderer
symbology = layer.symbology
symbology.updateRenderer('UniqueValueRenderer')
symbology.renderer.fields = ['ImagePath']

# Clear any existing classes
if hasattr(symbology.renderer, 'groups') and len(symbology.renderer.groups) > 0:
    symbology.renderer.groups[0].classes.clear()

# Add a class for each unique value in the ImagePath field
unique_values = set()
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(layer, ['ImagePath']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        unique_values.add(row[0])

for value in unique_values:
    if value:
        symbol = symbology.renderer.groups[0].classes.add(value)
        symbol.symbol.applySymbolFromGallery('Picture Marker Symbol')
        symbol.symbol.markerSymbol.url = value

# Apply the symbology to the layer
layer.symbology = symbology

# Refresh the active view
arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT").activeView.refresh()


I assume you have replaced map, field and layer names with your real data?

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162064/displaying-images-next-to-features-in-arcmap#162218

@Hornbydd yes of course. The code was updated in the testing

@FelixIP OMG let me give this a test and see if I can get this to work. I'll come back to you
